# How to drive NFET with current sink (LP5569)?

Tags: mosfet, current-sink

I have a circuit where LP55231 is driving NFET and the load is a LED. It's working fine.
[image: LP55231 circuit]

Now I need to switch LP55231 to LP5569. The difference is that LP55231 PWM output is current source and LP5569 PWM output is current sink.

[image: LP55231]

[image: LP5569]

How do I need to change the circuit to get it work with LP5569?
I tried to figure it out with LTspice, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Why is R32 shorted? I don't think this is related to your question but I can't help but be curious.

Comment: A reverse diode?

Comment: If you use a MOSFET on output of LPC55xx, you lost the internal current source benefits.